# AWX 1.0.7.2: another ansible playbook running properly with CLI and failing with AWX

Tags: ansible, ansible-awx

I have posted recently some examples of ansible playbooks tested and running as expected with the CLI and which stop working as soon as imported in AWX. here is another example:

```
- name: empty known_hosts
  file:
    state: absent
    path: /root/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Here is the execution with the CLI:

```
TASK [configure-admin : empty known_hosts]
**************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]
```

and here is what happened in AWX:

```
TASK [configure-admin : empty known_hosts] 
*************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "gid": 0, "group": "root", "mode": "0644", "msg": 
"unlinking failed: [Errno 116] Stale file handle: '/root/.ssh/known_hosts' ", "owner": "root", 
"path": "/root/.ssh/known_hosts", "size": 34932, "state": "file", "uid": 0}
```

I have googled a lot looking for what might be causing this "Stale file handle" error. I found different posts talking about NFS mount points, but this doesn't have anything to do with my context.

Comment: @Zeitounator: so you think that in order to use AWX, organizations must rewrite playbooks such that to comply with better ideas ? My point, and the point of this post, is not to discuss wether this idea is good or not, but to say that playbooks working properly in CLI don't work in AWX. And if you have a good idea of what to do in order to get these playbooks working, I'd be interested. Otherwise ...

Comment: are you running the playbook with same user in cli and awx?

Comment: Can you just use the `lineinfile` to empty the file, rather than trying to delete it?

Comment: @Zeitounator: many thanks for your advise but it doesn't help as not at all related to the issue I'm raising.

Comment: @Jack: I certainly could but the point is not how to modify playbooks, but how to use the service such that all the running playbooks continue to run properly in AWX ? My understanding is that AWX is an ansible machine aiming at centralizing playbooks, roles and other ansible related artifacts. As such, one doesn't expect that these artifacts have to be modified in order to run properly 'cause, if this is the case, AWX is not any worth. Organizations might have dozens of playbooks that are used with the CLI and that couldn't be rewritten just to please AWX.

Comment: You could just not run AWX in a docker container.

Comment: @Jack: why is that ?

Comment: @Nicolas Because docker locks things down that are not locked down outside of the container.